# How to move a Character Sideways without causing any overflows in Unity?

Tags: physics, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a 3D endless runner game for some time when I faced this issue. During sideways movement, after switching each lane, my character just jumps back (-z axis) a couple of decimals which is very noticeable for someone who's playing the game; feeling like he's teleporting backward a few decimals. The issue came up after adding this simple code `transform.position = locationAfterChangingLane;` which stopped the overflowing of sideways movement. It did stop overflowing but made this annoying bug.

*(code line situated in the `isChangingLane` if statement in update method.)*

Here's my script (full, also I have commented where the above code line for easy reference.)

```
//Variables for Lane switching 
    private bool isChangingLane = false;
    private Vector3 locationAfterChanginLane = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 sideWayMovementDistance = Vector3.right * 2f; // This might be the case that triggers abnormal movements
    private float sideWaySpeed = 6f;

    public enum Lane
    {
        Left,
        Right,
        Center
    }

    public enum MoveDirection
    {
        Left,
        Right,
        None
    }

    Lane currentLane = Lane.Center;

     void Update()
    {
        currentBaseState = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);

        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            verticalVelocity = -0.5f;
            if (currentBaseState.fullPathHash == locoState)
            {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                {
                    verticalVelocity = 18f;

                    anim.SetBool("Jump", true);
                }
                else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
                {
                    anim.SetBool("Slide", true);
                }

            }

            MoveLeftRight(); // This is the method to move right and left.

            if (isChangingLane)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(transform.position.x - locationAfterChanginLane.x) < 0.1f)
                {
                    isChangingLane = false;
                    moveVector.x = 0;
                    transform.position = locationAfterChangingLane; // This is the code which throws this issue.
                }
            }



        }
    }

    private void MoveLeftRight()
    {

        MoveDirection requestedMoveDirection = MoveDirection.None;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && !isChangingLane)
        {
            requestedMoveDirection = MoveDirection.Left;
            isChangingLane = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && !isChangingLane)
        {
            requestedMoveDirection = MoveDirection.Right;
            isChangingLane = true;
        }

        switch (requestedMoveDirection)
        {
            case MoveDirection.Right:
                if (currentLane == Lane.Right)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Right Lane");
                    break; //Do nothing when in right lane.

                }
                else if (currentLane == Lane.Center)
                {
                    locationAfterChanginLane = transform.position + sideWayMovementDistance;
                    moveVector.x = +sideWaySpeed;

                    currentLane = Lane.Right;
                    Debug.Log("Center --> Right");
                }
                else if (currentLane == Lane.Left)
                {
                    locationAfterChanginLane = transform.position + sideWayMovementDistance;
                    moveVector.x = +sideWaySpeed;

                    currentLane = Lane.Center;
                    Debug.Log("Left --> Center");
                }
                break;
            case MoveDirection.Left:
                if (currentLane == Lane.Left)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Left Lane");
                    break; //Do nothing when in left lane.
                }
                else if (currentLane == Lane.Center)
                {
                    locationAfterChanginLane = transform.position - sideWayMovementDistance;
                    moveVector.x = -sideWaySpeed;

                    currentLane = Lane.Left;

                    Debug.Log("Center --> Left");
                }
                else if (currentLane == Lane.Right)
                {
                    locationAfterChanginLane = transform.position - sideWayMovementDistance;
                    moveVector.x = -sideWaySpeed;

                    currentLane = Lane.Center;

                    Debug.Log("Right --> Center");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. How do I solve this? Also can you kindly explain why this happens? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a non-instantaneous movement animation as your character changes lane. That's good, but it also looks like you save the destination point at the moment that someone presses left or right. This position is stored in memory, and then about 0.5 sec later when they arrive at that lane fully, it reuses that position - which has stayed behind them.

A quick fix would be, once the lane movement animation has ended, just change locationAfterChangingLane's Z component to match the player's current Z component. Or, instead of saving and setting that vector, apply a Math.Max/Math.Min operation to the player's location so that they don't go past a certain maximum.

Another side note: I've seen some people run into math issues when playing their infinite runner for more than a few minutes because all their numbers are entering high ranges. It's possible that you'd want to consider simply having sections of the world simply "slide past" a still protagonist and be recycled behind him, so that even after 20 minutes of playing he's still at (0, 0, 0)

Comment: Great! I would consider your side note because many of the unity users says that better move the world than the player. So I would try and see how to move the sections of the world. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Eh, I don't know about shifting the world.  This comes back to clamping values.  It helps prevent your float from bleeding everywhere with unnecessary imprecision.